# Not able to display the data which has fetch from rest API in react js

Tags: java, reactjs

I have the react code which fetch the data through rest api but I am not able to display the JSon data. Please find below code

import React from 'react';

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    d: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/login/?username=abc&password=welcome1`)
    .then(res => {
      const d = res.data;
      this.setState({ d });
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
      { this.state.d}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the relevant React code

Answer (score 0):

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = { key: []};
```

}

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/login/?username=abc&password=welcome1`)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState(key: res.data);
    })
```

}

```
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
      { this.state.key}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not really setting state, or I haven't seen that syntax.

Typically, I'd do something like...

```
this.setState({ stateProp: valueToAssign });
```

So, in your case...

```
this.setState({ d: res.data });
```

I think you're lacking a constructor with class.  E.g. from the react site.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Don't call this.setState() here!
    this.state = { counter: 0 };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

And so in your case...

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { d: [] };

}
```

To be sure I'm assigning the right value, I'd do a 'console.log(res.data)' to inspect.

Answer (score 0):

It does really depend on the format of the response from the API.
You can't render an object or an array like this:

```
render() {
  const object = {foo: 'bar'};
  return (
    <div>
      {object}
    </div>
}
```

But you can render it like this:

```
render() {
  const object = {foo: 'bar'};
  return (
    <div>
      {object.foo}
    </div>
}
```